# JDBC data source not working when project deployed on tomcat

Tags: java, mysql, eclipse, tomcat, mariadb

I have developed a servlet which calls a MariaDB database through a JDNI datasource. This works fine when I run the web project within eclipse on a tomcat server run within eclipse.

However, when I deploy the project on a tomcat server outside eclipse, using a WAR file, the same servlet does not work. For testing purposes, the project also contains another servlet that connect directly (i.e. not using the JDNI datasource) to the same mariaDB and it works fine even when deployed to tomcat server outside eclipse.
I am running out of ideas concerning what could possibly be wrong and would greatly appreciate if someone could shed some light.

Configuration information:

- OS : macOS High Sierra
- tomcat version : 8.5
- eclipse : Neon.2., release 4.6.2
- Java : 8
- MariaDB driver : mariadb-java-client-2.2.0

Outiside eclipse, The driver is in two locations:

- /tomcat-folder/lib
- /tomcat-folder/webapps/my-app/WEB-INF/lib (from the WAR file)

I have added the following resource reference to the application web.xml file:

```
<resource-ref>
    <description>DB Connection</description>
    <res-ref-name>jdbc/MYDB</res-ref-name>
    <res-type>javax.sql.DataSource</res-type>
    <res-auth>Container</res-auth>
</resource-ref>
```

I have added the following resource to /tomcat-folder/contf/context.xml:

```
<Resource name="jdbc/MYDB” auth="Container" type="javax.sql.DataSource"
               maxTotal="100" maxIdle="30" maxWaitMillis="10000"
               username="root" password="" driverClassName="org.mariadb.jdbc.Driver"
               url="jdbc:mariadb//localhost:3306/MYDB”/>
```

The error I get is :

```
java.sql.SQLException: Cannot create JDBC driver of class 'org.mariadb.jdbc.Driver' for connect URL 'jdbc:mariadb//localhost:3306/MYDB'
    at org.apache.tomcat.dbcp.dbcp2.BasicDataSource.createConnectionFactory(BasicDataSource.java:2167)
    at org.apache.tomcat.dbcp.dbcp2.BasicDataSource.createDataSource(BasicDataSource.java:2037)
    at org.apache.tomcat.dbcp.dbcp2.BasicDataSource.getConnection(BasicDataSource.java:1543)
    at DBConfigTest.getConnection(DBConfigTest.java:123)
    at DBConfigTest.doGet(DBConfigTest.java:59)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:622)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:729)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:230)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:165)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:192)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:165)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:198)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:96)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:474)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:140)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:79)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:624)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:87)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:349)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:783)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:66)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:789)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1437)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: No suitable driver
    at org.apache.tomcat.dbcp.dbcp2.BasicDataSource.createConnectionFactory(BasicDataSource.java:2158)
    ... 28 more
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at DBConfigTest.doGet(DBConfigTest.java:61)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:622)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:729)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:230)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:165)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:192)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:165)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:198)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:96)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:474)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:140)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:79)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:624)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:87)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:349)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:783)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:66)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:789)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1437)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

the servlet code is as follows:

```
import java.io.*;
import javax.servlet.*;
import javax.servlet.http.*;
import java.sql.*;
import javax.naming.InitialContext;
import javax.naming.Context;
import javax.naming.NamingException;
import javax.sql.DataSource;

public class DBConfigTest extends HttpServlet{
   public void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
      throws ServletException, IOException {

      // JDBC driver name and database URL
     // static final String JDBC_DRIVER = "org.mariadb.jdbc.Driver";  
     // static final String DB_URL="jdbc:mariadb://localhost/MYDB"+"?user=root&password=";

      //  Database credentials
     // static final String USER = "root";
     // static final String PASS = "";

      // Set response content type
      response.setContentType("text/html");
      PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();
      String title = "Database Result";

      String docType =
         "<!doctype html public \"-//w3c//dtd html 4.0 " + "transitional//en\">\n";

      out.println(docType +
         "<html>\n" +
         "<head><title>" + title + "</title></head>\n" +
         "<body bgcolor = \"#f0f0f0\">\n" +
         "<h1 align = \"center\">" + title + "</h1>\n");

   // Execute SQL query
      //Statement stmt=null;
      //Connection conn=null;
      Connection connection=null;
      PreparedStatement statement=null;

      try {
         // Register JDBC driver
         //Class.forName("org.mariadb.jdbc.Driver");

         // Open a connection
         //conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mariadb://localhost/MYDB"+"?user=root&password=");

                connection = getConnection();
              String sql = "SELECT * FROM  ingredient";
              statement = connection.prepareStatement(sql);
              ResultSet rs = statement.executeQuery();

         // Execute SQL query
         /*stmt = conn.createStatement();
         String sql;
         sql = "SELECT * FROM  ingredient";
         ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery(sql);*/

         // Extract data from result set
         while(rs.next()){
            //Retrieve by column name
            int id  = rs.getInt("ingredient_id");
            String code = rs.getString("ingredient_code");
            String description = rs.getString("ingredient_description");

            //Display values
            out.println("ID: " + id + "<br>");
            out.println(", Code: " + code + "<br>");
            out.println(", Description: " + description + "<br>");

         }
         out.println("</body></html>");

         // Clean-up environment
         rs.close();
         statement.close();
         connection.close();
      } catch(SQLException se) {
         //Handle errors for JDBC
         se.printStackTrace();
      } catch(Exception e) {
         //Handle errors for Class.forName
         e.printStackTrace();
      } finally {
         //finally block used to close resources
         try {
            if(statement!=null)
               statement.close();
         } catch(SQLException se2) {
         } // nothing we can do
         try {
            if(connection!=null)
            connection.close();
         } catch(SQLException se) {
            se.printStackTrace();
         } //end finally try
      } //end try
   }



   private Connection getConnection() {
        Connection connection = null;
        try {
          /*InitialContext context = new InitialContext();
          DataSource dataSource = (DataSource) context.lookup("jdbc/MYDB");
          connection = dataSource.getConnection();*/

            Context initContext = new InitialContext();
            Context envContext  = (Context)initContext.lookup("java:/comp/env");
            DataSource ds = (DataSource)envContext.lookup("jdbc/MYDB");
            connection = ds.getConnection();


        } catch (NamingException e) {
          e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (SQLException e) {
          e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return connection;
      }
}
```

Comment: Are you sure that org.mariadb.jdbc.Driver is on the classpath?

Comment: You are missing a colon (`:`) in the JDBC URL, after `mariadb` and before `//`.

Comment: Hi Steve and Andreas, Thanks for your prompt answers. Applying Andreas' answer fixed my problem. I just added the ( : ) in context.xml of my tomcat server. This was taken into account by tomcat on the fly and fixed the problem with the resource definition.

Answer (score 1):

The url in the example below should be url="jdbc:mariadb://localhost:3306/MYDB”. A colon (:) in the JDBC URL, after mariadb and before //, was missing.

```
<Resource name="jdbc/MYDB” auth="Container" type="javax.sql.DataSource"
               maxTotal="100" maxIdle="30" maxWaitMillis="10000"
               username="root" password="" driverClassName="org.mariadb.jdbc.Driver"
               url="jdbc:mariadb//localhost:3306/MYDB”/>
```